# How can I make a table of contents for a markdown document with Python/AWK/SED?

Tags: python, sed, markdown, awk, table-of-contents

I have the following markdown document:

```
Heading-a
==========

---text---

Heading-b
------------

--- text ---

Heading-c
----------

--- text---

Heading-d
=======

--- text----

Heading-e
---

...
```

I would like to make a clickable table of contents out of it, similar to the way [LaTex](http://www.latex-project.org/) does, but can't find a tool that does this, which suggests to me that we should build one.

The tool should collect 'H1' headings and 'H2' headings such that it assigns the number 1 to `Heading-a` and the number 1.1. to `Heading-b`, 1.2. to `Heading-c`, 2. to `Heading-d`, 2.1. to `Heading-e` and so on, such that we should get the following Table of contents:

```
  1. Heading-a
  1.1. Heading-b
  1.2. Heading-c
  2. Heading-d
  2.1. Heading-e
```

How can I do this with Python/AWK/SED?

Comment: Why don't you just use LaTeX?

Comment: @jtbandes: The syntax of Markdown is easier to read, faster to type and easier to compile than that of LaTex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Markdown in Python](https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/) implementation has support for extensions one of which includes Table of Contents generation. Additionally [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) (which is a Haskell markup->PDF has support for markdown (in addition to a bunch of other formats) and can output pretty HTML, LaTeX, PDFs, etc.

Comment: Your answer raised another problem in installing the extensions at the thread http://superuser.com/questions/13075/to-install-markdowns-extensions-by-python

Answer (score 1):

If you already have headings, you can try [github-markdown-toc](https://github.com/ekalinin/github-markdown-toc.git) is able to process stdin, local and remote files, for example:

```
cat ~/projects/Dockerfile.vim/README.md | ./gh-md-toc -
```

or creating a local `README.md`:

```
./gh-md-toc ~/projects/Dockerfile.vim/README.md
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://alexandrenotebook.blogspot.com/2008/01/textile-vs-markdown-vs-multimarkdown-vs_10.html) for a comparison of lightweight markup languages with some information on tables of contents that might lead you in the direction of a solution.

Comment: The link is not working.

Comment: The link works for me.

Comment: It seems to be the case that the original author has just removed the blog post such that you have the article in your cache.

Comment: The article can be found at Google's cache: site:http://alexandrenotebook.blogspot.com/2008/01/textile-vs-markdown-vs-multimarkdown-vs_10.html