# To install Markdown's extensions by Python

Tags: python, markdown

The [installation notes](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Available_Extensions) (git://gitorious.org/python-markdown/mainline.git) say in the file `using_as_module.txt`

> One of the parameters that you can
>   pass is a list of Extensions.
>   Extensions 
>        must be available as python modules either within the
>   `markdown.extensions`
>        package or on your PYTHONPATH with names starting with `mdx_`,
>   followed by the 
>        name of the extension.  Thus, `extensions=['footnotes']` will
>   first look for 
>        the module `markdown.extensions.footnotes`,
>   then a module named 
>        `mdx_footnotes`.   See the documentation specific to the
>   extension you are 
>        using for help in specifying configuration settings for that
>   extension.

I put the folder "extensions" to ~/bin/python/ such that my PYTHONPATH is the following

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/masi/bin/python/:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/
```

The instructions say that I need to import the addons such that

```
import markdown
import <module-name>
```

However, I cannot see any module in my Python. This suggests me that the extensions are not available as "python modules - - on [my] PYTHONPATH with names starting with mdx_ - -."

**How can you get Markdown's extensions to work?**

---

2nd attempt

I run at ~/bin/markdown

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/python-markdown/mainline.git python-markdown
cd python-markdown
python setup.py install
```

I put the folder `/Users/masi/bin/markdown/python-markdown/build` to my PATH because the installation message suggests me that is the new location of the extensions.

I have the following in a test markdown -document

```
[TOC]
-- headings here with # -format ---
```

However, I do not get the table of contents. 
This suggests me that we need to somehow activate the extensions when we compile by the markdown.py -script. **The problem returns to my first quoted text which I is rather confusing to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to setup a `virtualenv` when I use python for any sort of project. So on debian based systems I install `pip` and `virtualenv`

```
sudo aptitude install python-pip python-virtualenv
```

Then if using python markdown, I would make my virtual environment and use `pip` to install `python-markdown` and `ElementTree`

```
virtualenv mynewbook
pip -E mynewbook install -U Markdown ElementTree
```

To make life easier I usually set my environment to the local virtual environment after changing to the new project directory

```
cd mynewbook
source bin/activate
```

Then with my book in the file mybook.markdown with the format

```
[TOC]

Heading-a
==========

---text---

Heading-b
------------
```

I just have to run

```
markdown mybook.markdown -f mybook.html -x toc
```

When you're done with your virtual environment it's as simple as typing

```
deactivate
```